# How to get a single operator from the stmaryrd package?

Tags: symbols, packages, math-operators

I am preparing a math document, and would like to use the `\bigtriangleup` math operator from the package `stmaryrd`. However, calling the entire package is not an option as it overwrites several commands from `mathabx` which I am also using. Is there a way I can extract this operator (possibly using a different name, so that `mathabx`'s `\bigtriangleup` binary operator isn't affected) without having to use the package?

Comment: @Andrew, I have seen that post, but am unable to modify it to my needs, because it is rather general, and I am not very familiar with the internal workings of LaTeX.

Comment: @sami.spricht.sprache So please show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've managed a workaround, by using the stmaryrd package and importing the specific mathabx symbols I need, which seems to work fine, using the method in @Andrew's answer below. Basically, the opposite of what I was trying initially.

Answer (score 3):

As the OP thinks that this is not a duplicate, following the general recipe in [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) (and, in fact shortening it quite a bit in this example), the code below seem to work because it produces

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stmry}{U}{stmry}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol\stmarybigtriangleup\mathop{stmry}{"61}

\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

  St Mary: $\stmarybigtriangleup$

  Mathxba: $\bigtriangleup$

\end{document}
```

Given the post referred to above, the only thing that is not obvious is the definition of `\stmarybigtriangleup`, which can be found by looking in stmaryrd.sty. Of course, rather than `\stmarybigtriangleup`, you could call this anything you like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is similar to what I tried first, but unfortunately, the method has a few problems of its own. For example, it completely messes up the `\colon` symbol that I use, replacing it with a negation sign, changes `\acute` to `\supseteq` etc. So, it doesn't interfere with `mathabx` (`\bigtriangleup` is safe), but has other issues.

Comment: @sami.spricht.sprache Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) saying exactly what your issues are - I answered your question but could not guess your other constraints. This said,  problems with other fonts/symbols should not occur so it is probably something else that is causing your problems. Without more information about what you are doing it is really hard to help you, which is why a MWE is useful. Also, when you ask questions it is better to let people know what you have tried, and why it didn't work, as this saves time for everyone.

Comment: the reason I didn't post a minimal example is because my document is huge (not minimal). But I've managed a workaround, by using the `stmaryrd` package and importing the specific `mathabx` symbols I need, which seems to work fine. Thanks again for your help.